# How to transfer interface to specified type by using generic

Tags: go

There is an Interface declare and many structs that implement it

```
type DataInterface interface {
    Get(string) string
}

type DataA struct {
    d map[string]string
}

func (d *DataA) Get(key string) string {
    return d.d[key]
}

func (d *DataA) GetId() string {
    return d.Get("id")
}

type DataB struct {
    d map[string]string
}

func (d *DataB) Get(key string) string {
    return d.d[key]
}

func (d *DataB) GetFile() string {
    return d.Get("file")
}


type DataC...
```

Also includes `DataC,D,E...`

and I will store these `DataX` structs instance into a `type DataSlice []DataInterface`

Now, If I want to get `DataX` , I can do this:

```
type DataSlice []DataInterface
func (d DataSlice) GetA() []*DataA {
    var ret []*DataA
    for _, di := range d {
        if v, ok := di.(*DataA); ok {
            ret = append(ret, v)
        }
    }
    return ret
}

func (d DataSlice) GetB() []*DataB {
    var ret []*DataB
    for _, di := range d {
        if v, ok := di.(*DataB); ok {
            ret = append(ret, v)
        }
    }
    return ret
}

func (d DataSlice) GetC() .....
```

Obviously there's a lot of repetitive code here:

```
var ret []*DataX
for _, di := range d {
    if v, ok := di.(*DataX); ok {
        ret = append(ret, v)
    }
}
```

So I think about that I can use generic to slove this, then I define this function:

```
func GetDataX[T any] (d DataInterface) *T {
    return d.(*T)
}
```

but got error: `Impossible type assertion: '*T' does not implement 'DataInterface`

So, I want to know is this way really impossible? Or it could be completed by the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle your needs with the following code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// interface
type DataInterface interface {
    Get(string) string
}

// struct implementing the interface
type DataA struct {
    d map[string]string
}

func (d DataA) Get(key string) string {
    return d.d[key]
}

type DataB struct {
    d map[string]string
}

func (d DataB) Get(key string) string {
    return d.d[key]
}

type DataSlice []DataInterface

func GetDataX[T any](d DataInterface) T {
    return d.(T)
}

func main() {
    a := DataA{map[string]string{"a": "1"}}
    b := DataB{map[string]string{"b": "2"}}

    ds := DataSlice{a, b}

    for _, v := range ds {
        if value, ok := v.(DataA); ok {
            fmt.Printf("A\t%q\n", GetDataX[DataA](value))
            continue
        }

        if value, ok := v.(DataB); ok {
            fmt.Printf("B\t%q\n", GetDataX[DataB](value))
            continue
        }

        // add unknown type handling logic here
    }
}
```

First, I simplified the code to take into consideration only the `DataA` and `DataB` structs. Then, I changed the **pointer receivers** to **value receivers** as you're not going to change the state of the actual instance passed to the methods. Thanks to this change the `GetDataX` works successfully and you're able to get the info for all of your similar structs.

Let me know if this solves your issues or if you need something else, thanks!